# How to order google calendar feed by start date

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-calendar-api

How to order Google Calendar feed by start date, which is sooner to the present? I tried a lot of different ways but it didn't happened. I think there are some functions from API, but I can't get them working. Sorry for my bad English!

Here is my code

`

```
    function outputCalendar($client)

    {

    $gdataCal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);

    $eventFeed = $gdataCal->getCalendarEventFeed();





    $d = 0;

    foreach ($eventFeed as $event):

    $event->id->text = str_replace ("http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full/", "", $event->id->text);



      $descrEvent = $event->getContent();



    if(mb_strlen($descrEvent, "UTF-8") > 200)
        $descrEvent = mb_substr($descrEvent, 0, 200, "UTF-8")."...";          

    ?>



    <div class="slider-container">

    <span style="font-weight: bold;"><?= stripslashes($event->title->text); ?></span><br />

    <span class="st">Start date: <?= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($event->when['0']->startTime)); ?></span> 

    <span class="et">End date: <?= date('Y-m-d', strtotime($event->when['0']->endTime)); ?></span>

    <span class="st"><?= stripslashes($event->where['0']->valueString); ?></span><br />

    <span class="str"><?= stripslashes($descrEvent); ?></span>

    </div>

    <? 

    $d++;



    endforeach; 

    }



    require_once 'Zend/Loader.php';

    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata');

    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_AuthSub');

    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin');

    Zend_Loader::loadClass('Zend_Gdata_Calendar');



    $user = 'killerskunk@gmail.com';

    $pass = 'mr_bean';

    $service = Zend_Gdata_Calendar::AUTH_SERVICE_NAME; // predefined service name for calendar



    $client = Zend_Gdata_ClientLogin::getHttpClient($user,$pass,$service);



    outputCalendar($client);

    ?>`
```

Comment: You need to add `orderby=starttime` in the URL (no idea how to do it using ZEND GData).

Comment: I use that url to get the event code.. As you can see there is str_replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it by inserting

```
$query = $gdataCal->newEventQuery();
$query->setVisibility('private');
$query->setOrderby('starttime');
$query->setSortOrder('ascending');
$eventFeed = $gdataCal->getCalendarEventFeed($query);
```

after

```
$gdataCal = new Zend_Gdata_Calendar($client);
```